# Right-hand-side assignment - how is this possible?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have some basic angular code grabbing navigation menus for logged in and logged out users and storing the menus in `$localStorage` then toggling them to the `$rootScope` when the user logs in/out etc.

Below is a simplified version of that code for the purposes of this question.

It seems like one of the lines of code actually results the left-hand-side to be assigned to the right.

```
$localStorage.navigation = {};
$rootScope.nav = {};

// save the nav menus in local storage
$localStorage.navigation.loggedIn = "nav menu json";    

// use local storage to set the rootscope
$rootScope.nav = $localStorage.navigation;  

/*  should be..
    $rootScope.nav = {loggedIn:'nav menu json'};
    $localStorage.navigation = {loggedIn:'nav menu json'};
*/

// set the nav menu - Right-hand-assignment???
$rootScope.nav.current = $localStorage.navigation.loggedIn;

/*  should be..
    $rootScope.nav = { loggedIn:'nav menu json', current: 'nav menu json' };
    $localStorage.navigation = { loggedIn:'nav menu json' };
*/

console.log($rootScope.nav.current);    // 'nav menu json' as expected
console.log($localStorage.navigation.current);    // 'nav menu json', WHAT??!!

/*  actually..
    $rootScope.nav = { loggedIn:'nav menu json', current: 'nav menu json' };
    $localStorage.navigation = { loggedIn:'nav menu json', current: 'nav menu json' };
*/
```

What in the hell is happening here??

Comment: This `$rootScope.nav = $localStorage.navigation;` is passing an object reference... overwriting the initial empty object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `$localStorage.navigation` is an object not a primitive (`Boolean`, `Number`, `String`), this line assigns a *reference*, not a *copy* of `$localStorage.navigation` to `$rootScope.nav`:

```
$rootScope.nav = $localStorage.navigation;
```

At this point, `$localStorage.navigation` and `$rootScope.nav` are two references to exactly the same object. This line:

```
$rootScope.nav.current = $localStorage.navigation.loggedIn;
```

Is assigning the primitive value `$localStorage.navigation.loggedIn` to `$rootScope.nav.current`, but since `$localStorage.navigation` and `$rootScope.nav` are the exact same object, `$localStorage.navigation.current` refers to the same value as `$rootScope.nav.current`

To be clear, right-hand-side assignment is *not possible*.

Comment: well looks like I learned something today. thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it helped!